# Views display settings are in the database but don't show up in views UI

Tags: views, 6, features

I'm trying to create a copy of a live site and use it as test site, but I have troubles with a view whose settings are in the database, which does not show up correctly in the UI.

I copied the site by installing Drupal, the required modules, including some custom features, and exporting the database.

The view is defined in a feature, and also exists in the *views_view* and *views_display* database tables. I have not reverted the feature, so I believe the feature code should be ignored in favor of whatever is in the database.

In the database and in the feature, the view has display with some settings that overrides the default display, for example *Header: PHP Code* overrides *Header: None*. In the UI, the added display exists, but, except for *Name*, all of its overridden settings, relationships, arguments, fields, and filters are gone.

That is the case for some of the other displays on the view too. A display lost its relationships, arguments, and sort criteria, but not its fields and filters.

I've tried running `drush cc all`, clearing the cache from *Admin > Site Building > Views > Tools*, and deleting all rows from the *views_object_cache* table; None of them helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test running on a 32-bit system, and the [Role Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_export) module did not support 32-bit systems. (See [32-bit overflow in role_export_generate_id](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_export/issues/1334134), a bug report that is still open and it will never be fixed, since Drupal 6 is no longer supported.)

Once MAMP has been upgraded to a 64-bit version, the view worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW - you might want to install drush and use the drush archive-dump command which will extract your entire site (database, drupal instance and files) into a single tarball file.  You can then use drush archive-restore to import that site into a different site on the same or different machine.

There are other ways, of course, but this seems to be one of the easiest as there is nothing to remember or think about other than doing it.

Good luck - B

Answer (score 0):

Memcache seems like a possible cuplrit. Try clearing out memcache cache manually. Drupal generally dislikes DB edit's and may not understand to requery the actual DB, but instead is getting the values from Memcache.

/etc/init.d/memcached restart

Comment: Pretty sure memcached isn't running. This is on MAMP and I haven't enabled memcached in php.ini, and there's no memcached process running on my system.