# Where is a UI-configured Views display definition read from?

Tags: views

**General question:** In Views 3, on Drupal 7, when a View display in configured using Views UI, what is the location where the configuration is 'read' and applied when...:

- ...creating a query to generate a page?
- ...loading its Views UI page (I believe this is the table `views_display`)?

---

**Background / why asking:** I've encountered a very strange problem where (despite repeatedly clearing all caches including Views cache and even disabling Views caching in Views advanced settings), the output a view generates *in situ* in a panel / block on the page doesn't match the rules shown for it on editting it in Views UI.

**Edit:** Actually, looks like they are both coming from the same place but the two displays got merged and became non-overridden in a strange way. I'll keep this open as I'd like to know for sure where these are stored in the DB for future reference anyway.

---

It's a dev environment with no memcache / memcached / boost etc - no additional layers of caching.

There's [one existing question where someone finds Views UI somehow 'loses' the override settings for a views display](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/26259/views-display-settings-are-in-the-database-but-dont-show-up-in-views-ui), but it's not related to my case: there's nothing on my general question, the cause doesn't apply in my case, and none of the suggestions there help. There's also [a question which includes my general question on drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1850142) but none of the replies answer my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table `{views_view}` has the list of views.  The more or less matches up with what is on admin/structure/views, except for views created by modules.

The table `{views_display}` has displays for each view, keyed to `{views_view}` with the `vid` column.  The `id` column is the machine name from admin/structure/views/view/foo/edit.  There is one row per display.  The `display_options` column has a serialized version settings from the edit form, and it more or less matches up with the display section when you export a view from admin/structure/views/view/foo/export.  I am also pretty sure that the actual query is essentially built up from the same column.

In my years of using a sledgehammer to make Drupal do what my clients need, I don't recall ever poking through the views tables for anything.  I will periodically look at an export to see what is going on with a view, and export/edit/import views to adjust things, though.